# Resorting a group of rows

Tags: mysql, sorting, join, sql-update, window-functions

Let's say I have the following table, rankings,

```
|film_id|user_id|rank|
|-------|-------|----|
|1      |1      |2   |
|2      |1      |3   |
|3      |1      |1   |
|1      |2      |2   |
|2      |2      |1   |
|3      |2      |3   |
```

and I delete film id `2`.

Is there a MySQL way to rerank the remaining films per user in a single query, such:

```
|film_id|user_id|rank|
|-------|-------|----|
|1      |1      |2   |
|3      |1      |1   |
|1      |2      |1   | <- changed from 2 to 1
|3      |2      |2   | <- changed from 3 to 2
```

Edit for clarity: I'm not sure I would call it a formula, exactly, but all I want to do is have a query that loads the remaining films in order of their rank, and then rebuild the ranking in that same order, and consecutive.

In other words, if after deleting a row, a user's rankings went 1,2,4,5,6, I want it to be rebuilt to be consecutive starting at 1 (1,2,3,4,5).

Thank you!

Comment: The obvious way is to recalculate the rankings on the same basis as they were calculated before. There's nothing here that suggests how that was done.

Comment: @TangentiallyPerpendicular, sorry, that didn't seem particularly relevant to the question, but happy to elaborate. It's not calculated, per se. It's set by the user. The app logic takes a list of film_ids in order and updates the rank as appropriate. That's an easy, inexpensive way to set the order in the case of the user sorting. In the case of handling a deletion, I wondered if it might be possible and faster to handle the details all within the DB since all the info needed is already in the DB.

Comment: If you provide the formula to compute the rank, it's perfectly possible to do so. At the moment the question lacks this information, so it's not possible to answer it.

Comment: @TheImpaler, Maybe I'm just under-thinking it, I don't look at is a formula. I guess it is though. I just want to remove gaps left by deleting a row, on a per user basis. I updated the question with more information.

Comment: Do you want to update the table with the new rankings or just a select query? Also, what is your version of MySql?

Comment: @forpas, update the table and v8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Join the table to a query that uses `ROW_NUMBER()` window function to rebuild the rankings:

```
UPDATE tablename t1
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY `rank`) rn
  FROM tablename
) t2 ON t2.film_id = t1.film_id AND t2.user_id = t1.user_id
SET t1.`rank` = t2.rn
WHERE t1.`rank` <> t2.rn; -- actually this in not needed 
                          -- as MySql does not perform the update 
                          -- if the current and new values are the same
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=8302aa1883c6b8e50da6de449fd018e5).

Comment: This worked beautifully! Thank you. I love solutions like this that keep the processing where it is most efficiently handled, but I just could not figure it out. (I have some research to do on the `OVER (PARTITION BY...` clause because I have not seen that before.)